# How to get the border of adjacent and non-adjacent squares to all be equal?

Tags: html, css, image, border

I am trying to recreate a "pixelated" version of Space Invaders in HTML/CSS using individual `30px` squares with a `2px` border.

Thanks to Sunyatasattva, this is what I have so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/wnhzp/

However, notice that only the "inner" squares have the correct `2px` black border all around them, and that any side of an "outer" square that is not facing an adjacent square only has a `1px` border.

How can I get **every** square to have the proper `2px` border?

Answer (score 1):

Add `margin:1px` to your div styling.

---

UPDATE: Oh, I see what you want.  Here you go: [jsfiddle.net/nunzabar/Wna8L/](http://jsfiddle.net/nunzabar/Wna8L/)

I had to manually set each border.  The invader looks awesome now.

Comment: But then I lose the `2px`black border I wanted and just have a `1px` border with white space in between: http://jsfiddle.net/wnhzp/1/

Comment: @Programmer you are not using nunzabar jsfiddle in your rebuttal.. good job nunzaber i just +1'ed you